# Accent menu gone in Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I'm unable to get the accent menu to show up when I hold down a key. Do I have to enable the long-press accent menu in Mavericks somehow manually?

Comment: What apps are you trying it with? Do you have any apps that might customise the keyboard (KeyRemap4MacBook, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Got it working by adding a second language in the **Language & Region** pref pane and rebooting.

Now the menu shows up.

Comment: So you only had one language in that list to start with?  Had you removed some earlier or was it that way from the beginning?

Comment: Had only one language in the list to start with